# Intellij IDEA: Key combination based on their position on an AZERTY keyboard while typing is based on QWERTY

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.3 (182.4129.33), on a french Fedora that has QWERTY layout enabled (the only layout I can work with).

While typing, the QWERTY layout is taken into account. However, when I use shortcuts, it is the french AZERTY layout that takes over.

For instance, while in an open document, pressing A produces an "a" character in my document, all to my contentment. However, pressing Ctrl + A fires the action defined for Ctrl + Q instead of "Select All". 'A' on a QWERTY keyboard maps to 'Q' on an AWERTY one.

This is very confusing as the behavior of the IDE is incoherent. Same key stroke is mapped differently depending whether it is accompanied with a modifier (Alt, Ctr or both) or not.

### To reproduce

- Install IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate (idea-IU-182.4129.33) on a french Fedora, with QWERTY layout enabled.
- Open IntelliJ IDEA.
- In an open document press Ctrl + A.

### Expected result

"Select All", the action defined by Ctrl + A combination, being fired.

### What actually happens

The action defined by Ctrl + Q is fired instead. A's position on a QWERTY keyboard maps to Q on an AZERTY french keyboard.

### Fixes I tried (and didn't work)

- Update IntelliJ to the latest version (I previously had 2017.1).
- Add `-Dcom.jetbrains.use.old.keyevent.processing=true` in Custom Properties `idea.properties` the restarting IntelliJ IDEA.
- Set environment variables `LANG` and `LC_ALL` to `fr_FR.UTF-8` prior to starting IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, and found this command which fix my problem.

`setxkbmap fr`

However, I don't know why intellij need to have this settings defined, but it work.